# How to take this limit?

Tags: limits, physics

So I have an equation

$y(t) = \dfrac{1}{\alpha}(v_0sin(\theta) + \dfrac{g}{\alpha})(1-e^{-\alpha t}) - \dfrac{gt}{\alpha}$

And am supposed to show that if we take $\alpha$ to be small, then $y(t)$ reduces to

$y_2(t) = v_0sin(\theta)t - \dfrac{gt^2}{2}$

---

**First part of my issue:**

I am able to get the factor of $t$ that it seems I need. In the limit of $\alpha \rightarrow 0$,

$\dfrac{1}{\alpha}(1 - e^{-\alpha t}) \rightarrow t$

I actually discovered this while messing around with some values, I can't find a way to actually prove it on paper by setting $\alpha$ to a small value. But I do think the claim is true.

---

**Second issue:**

Other than that, I don't understand where the $\dfrac{gt^2}{2}$ comes from. Usingwhat I found above, I can simplify $y(t)$ to

$v_0 sin(\theta) t + \dfrac{gt}{\alpha} - \dfrac{gt}{\alpha} = v_0 sin(\theta) t$

But this obviously is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your work is correct in deriving $y$? This seems like it has to do with drag forces. Can you check your work and post the differential equation you got $y$ from?

Comment: @AOrtiz It does have to do with drag forces. But I was given no differential equation, I was simply given $y(t)$ and $y_2(t)$

Answer (score 2):

Proof of the stated limit:  $$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha} = -\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{(e^{-t})^\alpha - (e^{-t})^0}{\alpha - 0}.$$  But by definition of the derivative $$f'(x) = \lim_{\alpha \to x} \frac{f(\alpha) - f(x)}{\alpha - x}$$ with the choice $x = 0$, $f(x) = (e^{-t})^x$, we observe the limit is simply $$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha} = -\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{-tx}\right]_{x = 0} = \left[te^{-tx}\right]_{x=0} = t.$$

I should have been more careful with the second part of your question, which involves the calculation of a distinct limit from the one above:

$$\tag{$*$}\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha^2} - \frac{t}{\alpha}.$$  The reason for this is because we cannot in general write $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} g(x).$$  This much was pointed out by another answer that is as of this writing, deleted.

To evaluate this limit, we can employ the series expansion of $e^{-\alpha t}$ around $\alpha = 0$:  $$e^{-\alpha t} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\alpha t)^k}{k!} \sim 1 - \alpha t + \frac{(\alpha t)^2}{2} - O((\alpha t)^3).$$  Thus for fixed $t$, $$\frac{1 - e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha^2} - \frac{t}{\alpha} \sim -\frac{t}{\alpha} + \frac{\alpha t - (\alpha t)^2/2}{\alpha^2} + O(\alpha) \sim - \frac{t^2}{2} + O(\alpha),$$ and as $\alpha \to 0$, we obtain the desired behavior.  We can also use L'Hopital's rule to evaluate the limit $(*)$, or other methods.  Perhaps, suitably inspired by the use of the definition of derivative to evaluate the first limit, you might be able to formulate a similar argument for the second.

Comment: Thanks, that's a beautiful proof I would have never found. How did you see it?

Also, are you saying that $y(t)$ does _not_ reduce to $y_2(t)$ in the limit of a small $\alpha$? My assignment is specifically to show that this _does_ work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm surprised by how difficult this is. Even though your answer outlines what I must do, I don't think my calculus is sharp enough to actually arrive at an answer while displaying all steps in a satisfactory way. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$y=\frac{ \left(A+\frac{g}{\alpha }\right)\left(1-e^{-\alpha  t}\right)}{\alpha
   }-\frac{g t}{\alpha }$$ Use Taylor expansion around $\alpha=0$ $$e^{-\alpha  t}=1-\alpha  t+\frac{\alpha ^2 t^2}{2}+O\left(\alpha ^3\right)$$ which makes $$\frac{1-e^{-\alpha  t}}{\alpha
   }=t-\frac{\alpha  t^2}{2}+O\left(\alpha ^2\right)$$ Then $$y=\left(A+\frac{g}{\alpha }\right)\left(t-\frac{\alpha  t^2}{2}+O\left(\alpha ^2\right)\right)-\frac{g t}{\alpha }=\left(A t-\frac{g t^2}{2}\right)+O\left(\alpha \right)$$ Using one more term for the Taylor expansion, you could arrive to $$y=\left(A t-\frac{g t^2}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{6} \alpha  \left(g t^3-3 A
   t^2\right)+O\left(\alpha ^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Comment: What is the notation $O(x)$ supposed to mean in the context of Taylor expansion?